# Can I trust vector::size after an exception is thrown?

Tags: c++, function, exception, vector, stl

I am trying to understand how exceptions affect an `std::vector`. More precisely, I want to check the size of the vector, when an out of memory exception is thrown.

I mean something like this:

```
std::vector<int> v;
try {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < desiredSize; ++i)
        v.push_back(i);
}
catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
    cerr << "Out of memory! v.size() = " << v.size() << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Is that a good approach or should I keep track of the vector's size with an independent variable of mine?

Comment: What type is `v`?

Comment: Sorry @jotik, updated. It's an `std::vector`. I wonder if its datatype matters.

Comment: pls note memory exceptions are RARE on 64 bits machines.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [the documentation for `std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> If an exception is thrown (which can be due to `Allocator::allocate()` or element copy/move constructor/assignment), this function has no effect (strong exception guarantee).

So in case of failure, the last `push_back` which caused the exception will be rolled back, but everything else will be fine: your vector will contain all of the previously pushed elements, and will be in a consistent state.

Comment: Aha, that will do it! That means that not only I can check the size but recover from that exception and continue on with my program (if the size still makes sense for me). Thanks Q!

Comment: @gsamaras: Exception safety is one of the main benefits of reusing standard containers and types.

Comment: Yes I agree @BoundaryImposition, but when you are out of memory, you have to be careful!

Answer (score 11):

According to  [[vector.modifiers]](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.modifiers#1) (**emphasis** mine):

> *Remarks:* Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity.
>   Reallocation invalidates all the references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements in the sequence.
>   If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.
>   **If an exception is thrown other than by the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator, or move assignment operator of `T` or by any `InputIterator` operation there are no effects.**
>   If an exception is thrown while inserting a single element at the end and `T` is `CopyInsertable` or `is_­nothrow_­move_­constructible_­v<T>` is true, there are no effects.
>   Otherwise, if an exception is thrown by the move constructor of a non-`CopyInsertable` `T`, the effects are unspecified.

Since your `T` is `int` (and operations on integers never throw) you can only get the out-of-memory errors from `std::vector` when it attempts to allocate new memory for its contents, hence this function has no effect when throwing any exception and using `size()` afterwards is a perfectly valid approach.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions
If an exception is thrown (which can be due to Allocator::allocate() or element copy/move constructor/assignment), this function has no effect (strong exception guarantee).

If T's move constructor is not noexcept and T is not CopyInsertable into *this, vector will use the throwing move constructor. If it throws, the guarantee is waived and the effects are unspecified.